# Service Reference with Values in Elements

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, service-reference

I'm using a Service Reference to a Java Web Service returning XML like this:

```
<m_score value="3"><Explanation value="20.51">Class Count</Explanation>
    <Explanation value="-15.03">NCCI Governing Industry Group</Explanation>
    <Explanation value="-9.74">Combined Weighted Average Hazard Score</Explanation>
    <Explanation value="4.9">Policy Weighted Average Loss Cost Relative to Governing Class Loss Cost</Explanation>
    <Explanation value="-2.96">Governing Class Loss Cost</Explanation>
</m_score>
```

The problem is that when I generate the proxy and request/response objects, the data within the Explanation elements is not represented in the objects. There are only properties for the attributes within each of the elements.

Is there any way to have the explanation name returned as well? For example, 'NCCI Governing Industry Group', etc...

Thanks!

Edit - relevant parts of WSDL:

```
<complexType name="ExplanationType">
    <attribute name="value" use="required"/>
</complexType>
<complexType name="m_scoreInsuredResponseType">
    <sequence>
       <element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="Explanation" type="response:ExplanationType"/>
    </sequence>
    <attribute name="value" use="required"/>
</complexType>
```

Comment: Are you wanting to have a List<m_score> for example..? Perhaps using a Dictionary or HashTable may be what you are looking to use for starters..

Comment: In the response I get an m_score containing an Explanation[]. The problem is that the Explanation objects just have the value, and not the name.

Comment: can you share what the webservice looks like or the C# code that you are using to Invoke the webService call..?

Comment: I added pieces of the web service that are relevant - you can see that the ExplanationType only has a single property on it (value), so I'm not sure how to get the name.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I looked at this, but I think that lack of proper support for schema like this was a known bug. You *may* be able to work around this by implementing your own Explanation class with the XmlTextAttribute (and then changing the proxy to use it), e.g something similar to:

public class Explanation
{
[XmlAttribute] public string value;
[XmlText] public string theExplanation;
}

(You may need to tweak the above to account for namespaces, possibly add [XmlRoot], etc. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmltextattribute.aspx for some info.)